# PHP-GD Png Transparent Image turn black

Tags: php, png, alpha-transparency, php-gd

I am using JCrop in a project of mine (the user have to crop his face) and send the coordinates & source image to a PHP handler. The flow should be the following: based on the coordinates received the handler crop the image and use `imagecopy()` to put the newly created image (90x90 in my case) over an empty layout created with `ImageCreateTrueColor()`. This works fine so far but the next step is: i have to load a png image with a transparent section. (I hope i explain clear enough) which have the same width and height as the previous layout who has the croped area on it. The final step is to use again `imagecopy()` to put the png over the layout and have as final result the template with the transparent section covered by the crop made by the user. Here is my code:

```
$targ_w = $targ_h = 90;
$jpeg_quality = 100;
$src = $_POST['s'];
$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );
imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);
$layout = ImageCreateTrueColor(459,683);
imagecopy($layout, $dst_r, 263, 249, 0, 0, 90, 90);
$template = 'template.png';
$src_r = imagecreatefrompng($template);
$background = imagecolorallocate($src_r, 255, 255, 255);
imagecolortransparent($src_r, $background);
imagealphablending($src_r, false);
imagesavealpha($src_r, true);
imagecopy($layout, $src_r, 0, 0, 0, 0, 459, 683);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($src_r);
```

I've tried many things found online and nothing seems to work.
EDIT: The issue is that the transparent section is black instead of being there the cropped face. I really need some advise. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any reason you're disabling alpha blending on $src_r?

Comment: I've tried before with alpha blending true and is still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a class before, will it fix your problem? http://www.gdenhancer.com

Here is the [example](http://www.gdenhancer.com/index.php?content=methods&method=backgroundresize)

Comment: Example link is broken.